# Как убрать стандартную надпись из страницы магазина?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На вордпрессе уже всё перепробовал.

Я не могу понять как редактировать страницу магазина Woocomerce , она у меня пустая заисключением шапки «товары» и ниже написано «Здесь вы можете добавлять новые товары в ваш магазин»

[image]

Comment: Добавить товары - не?

Comment: Не помогло:((((